# Pine editor get True Range of a specific bar

Tags: pine-script

I'm rather new at pine script. I am trying to calculate the True Range of a specific candle with calculation of lowest low. (This is the stop loss part of a TDS Long Setup)

```
lastBuyLowestValSTOP = buySetup == 9 ? lowest(low, 9) : nz(lastBuyLowestValSTOP[1])
```

*This finds the lowest low value when buySetup criteria is met. Lets say it is 7th candle(9-2).*

Now I have the lowest value, I need **that** candle's `trueRange = high-low` data. So I can;

```
stopPoint = lastBuyLowestValSTOP - trueRange
```

But I dont know that candle's index neither its high or low. I checked `barssince()` but it requires a criteria. When I try;

```
lowestSinceIndex = buySetup == 9 ? barssince(lowest(low, 9)): nz(lowestSinceIndex[1])
```

This returns 0. How can I get that candle's high and low values. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("TrueRange", "TR", overlay=true)

ll = lowest(low,9)
lb = lowestbars(9)

hist = abs(lb)

trueRange = high[hist] - low[hist]

plot(na)
```